# JPA Native Query mapping

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have this query written in Spring Data JPA :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT x,y, sum(x,y) FROM table 
    WHERE x = ?1 groupby x,y ", nativeQuery = true)
```

and I have entity class as

```
@Entity
class abc {
    int x;
    int y;
//setter and getter
}
```

How to map the result of this query to a POJO or Entity class??

PS: This works:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE x = ?1 ", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an exception? The wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

You have to map the result of the query to a POJO created, by passing it .class into the query. This can be done by calling createNativeQuery() on entity manager. e.g., 
`List<abc> myList = (List<abc>)em.createNativeQuery("your query here", abc.class)`. abc.java should have following two things

- 1. attribute names matching to the column names in the select clause of the query and
  2. a default constructor